# Mongo DB Index is not being used

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query, nosql, query-optimization

```
{
    "uniqueId": "32e99dd2-a9e8-4549-b783-2b772d3c345f",
    "$and": [
      {
        "event.attributes.date": {
          "$gte": "2021-07-31T18:30:00Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "event.attributes.date": {
          "$lte": "2023-09-07T18:29:59.999Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "event.attributes.sender.id": "003084b8-82d1-4302-b2cd-62fc22ddcc7e"
      }
    ]
  }
```

This query is not hitting index and the query fails for lot of data. Please help

When the volume of data is high, the query is failing.

Comment: It's not using which index? What is it choosing to do instead? In what way is the query failing? Typically to answer questions about index usage and query plan selection we'd need to see the `.explain("allPlansExecution")` output for the query, please edit your question to add a link to that